# Can 4x4 matrix be used for multiple 3D transforms?

Tags: 3d, matrix-multiplication, matrix-transform

I am doing 3D transformations using a 4x4 matrix. When performing rotations, for example, I am creating a 4x4 rotation matrix and multiplying the two matrices together. This is working fine.

Currently, I have a loop to go over each set of 3D point data, multiplying them with the transform matrix. This requires creating a 1x4 matrix from the 3D point data, plus a 1 in the 4th column.

My question is: Could I apply the 4x4 transformation matrix to every point in the 3D object's point array by simply setting it up as a 4xN matrix and multiplying it by the 4x4 transformation matrix?

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled about your question. At first you say multiplying them works fine. But then you ask how to apply the transformations? Though applying them is what you're already doing, and in turn what you say you're doing. Could you clarify?

Comment: I'm currently applying a 4x4 to only one 3D point's worth of data. I would like to know if *all* points can be multiplied in a single multiplication operation. The difference would be applying the 4x4 transform matrix to one point at a time versus the transform matrix to all points stored in a single, large, table.

Comment: Ohh I see now. No, you'd have to go through each point and multiply it with the transformation matrix, to get the transformed point. If this isn't a general math question, then there might be a better overall solution. As an example, in graphics programming you'd apply these transformations at runtime, (most definitely) on the GPU in a vertex shader.

Comment: The answer is yes. Multiplying a 4x4 matrix with a 4xN matrix (provided you set up the rows and columns correctly), will lead to an Nx4 matrix containing the result you expect. However it is computationally the same amount of work as looping over your 3D point.

Perhaps if you were using a vector language like matlab, it might be easier to do it this way.